# Помогите разобраться со скриптом jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Мне нужно 2 div'a с классами tp-leftarrow и tp-rightarrow объединить в один div с классом container. Но к сожалению, в jquery я не силен и у меня не получается это сделать.

Буду очень благодарен за помощь.

Вот часть кода, я подозреваю что манипуляции нужно проводить в этой части:

```js
function d(e, n) {
    var r = e.find(".tp-bullets");
    var i = "";
    var s = n.navigationStyle;

    if (n.navigationArrows == "none") 
        i = "visibility:hidden;display:none";
    n.soloArrowStyle = "default";
    if (n.navigationArrows != "none" && n.navigationArrows != "nexttobullets") 
        s = n.soloArrowStyle;
    e.parent().append('<div style="' + i + '" class="tp-leftarrow tparrows ' + s + '"></div>');
    e.parent().append('<div style="' + i + '" class="tp-rightarrow tparrows ' + s + '"></div>');
    e.parent().find(".tp-rightarrow")
        .click(function() {
            if (n.transition == 0) {
                if (e.data("showus") != t && e.data("showus") != -1) 
                    n.next = e.data("showus") - 1;
                else n.next = n.next + 1;
                    e.data("showus", -1);
                if (n.next >= n.slideamount) n.next = 0;
                if (n.next < 0) n.next = 0;
                if (n.act != n.next) f(n, e)
            }
        });
    e.parent().find(".tp-leftarrow")
        .click(function() {
            if (n.transition == 0) {
                n.next = n.next - 1;
                n.leftarrowpressed = 1;
                if (n.next < 0) 
                    n.next = n.slideamount - 1;
                f(n, e)
            }
        });
    y(e, n)
}
```

Comment: У вас код кажется через сборщик прошел. Но эти два вроде и так в контейнере, попробуйте просто класс нужный ему добавить - `e.addClass('container')`

Comment: А можете, пожалуйста, на примере показать?
Эти два элемента существуют по отдельности друг от друга. На деле это две стрелки слайдера, которые я хочу объединить в контейнер чтобы задать ему нужную ширину.

Answer (score 3):

Странно, что так никто и не дал ответ, но я пришел к решению сам.

```js
      e.parent().append('<div class="container"><div class="tp-leftarrow tparrows"></div><div class="tp-rightarrow tparrows"></div></div>');
```